# To handle dynamic fields at scala end

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark-sql

scenario is like :
we are pulling data from mongo in JSON format and processing through spark .
At times we are not getting the desired field inside the complex datatype eg nested array of string or struct within array .

1. Is there any workaround while loading JSON file to put null values to the absent field.
   (validator checks)

2.If want to handle dynamic nature at scala end, how it is suppose to be.

```
def checkAvailableColumns(df: DataFrame, expectedColumnsInput: List[String]) : DataFrame = {
    expectedColumnsInput.foldLeft(df) {
        (df,column) => {
            if(df.columns.contains(column) == false) {
                df.withColumn(column,lit("null"))
            }
            else (df)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the above code to verify if columns are present in source side while comparing with the required column names ,if not present put null to that column.
Question here is how to get complex data type like array of struct into general column name so that i can compare it .
(i can using dot operator to pull column with struct but if that column doesn't exist my script will fail .

Comment: Please add more information with sample code which you tried  which is not working so others can help you

Comment: I have updated the code with which iam trying to solve the scenario.

Comment: What is your output data format if you are storing data in json format .. spark will skip null columns..try to use orc or parquet to store data

Comment: Yes srinivas i am using parquet to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Scala Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) class. Let's assume you have a

`case class JsonTemplate(optionalArray: Option[Seq[String]])`

And let's assume you get the valid json `{}`, the parser will put None as the value. And you will get the instance: JsonTemplate(None)